# How to really customize an "ubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso" image?

Tags: custom-distributions, custom-installer

I have a dream:), I want to customize an "ubuntu-11.04-alternate-amd64.iso" image. What is the best software/solution for it?

I want to customize these things (**ALL OF THEM is needed**):

- Customized package list: I don't need all that comes with the default install, but I have a few thats not inc. in the def. install.
- GUI: I don't want a Desktop Environment in it, I only want to use the Openbox WM.
- I want a "half-automated" install: the installer only asks for: 1 encryption password + timezone + 1 username/password.

  So e.g.: the installer automatically creates an encrypted VolumeGroup with the given password (partitions: 256 MB /boot + VG get's the rest of the place: in the VG: 10 GByte to `/` and 2 GByte to swap and the rest goes to `/home`). - **[I mean with full encryption](http://xercestech.com/full-system-encryption-for-linux.geek)**.
- Automatically configure a few apps: e.g.: Google Chrome/Firefox - e.g.: auto install WOT+NoScript in them.
- Automatically install & configure: [grsecurity](http://grsecurity.net/); [PaX](http://pax.grsecurity.net/); [Pro Police](http://www.research.ibm.com/trl/projects/security/ssp/);  [DigSig](http://disec.sourceforge.net/).
- Configure in a way that the OS will do all the updates automatically without user interaction.
- Set file associations, e.g.: VLC for all the video files, etc.
- Install a Local DNS cache + Privoxy proxy & configure them to use as default, e.g.: ns: 127.0.0.1, HTTP/S proxy: 127.0.0.1:8118
- Automatically set the `iptables` Firewall rules that I provide.

Thanks for any help reaching my goal. Have a nice day.

p.s.: All that in one ISO image file (so not like e.g.: boot from a PXE server, i need a custom image in my hand that already contains the needed packages(even extra pack.)  not that it downloads them when installing :P )

Comment: Thats a very nice wish list - please add to your question any research that you have done so that any answers dont replicate what you have already tried.

Comment: I think this will be a ~~good solution: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/InstallCDCustomization

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Site after site, and application after application... I'm sorry, but for me, all of he above is unnecessary, and will just make things more difficult. The method I prefer for creating a custom LiveCD is to simply mount the image, replicate the contents out, mount the squashfs, replicate the contents into a working directory, chroot in and have a ball. The majority of what you mentioned can be done by editing the default settings for each individual application, usually located under /usr/share/$applicationName/default, or is system wide and therefore has a config in /etc. If you modify everything while chrooted, you can then run mksquashfs on the working directory, replace the squashfs from the original liveCD and create your image. Ubuntu actually has a very comprehensive wiki for this.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCDCustomization

Edit: I'm sorry, I just realized that you referenced that article yesterday. I have stepped through it quite a few times, although mainly for the creation of custom portable live usb devices, and I can give you any help you need if you just send me a message.

Answer (score 5):

The last time I looked into this, there were several different methods, each with pros and cons.

I ended up using the Ubuntu port of Red Hat's kickstart. There's a decent GUI tool you can apt-get install: `system-config-kickstart`. It can definitely do the simple things, like skipping a windowing system or customizing a list of packages to install. It can even do simple partitioning, but I wouldn't count on being able to do LVM, let alone encrypted LVM. See further documentation here: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/i386/automatic-install.html

Once you have your ks.cfg, you can either specify it as an HTTP URL when booting, or you can build a new image with `genisoimage` that has the file at e.g. `/preseed/ks.cfg` and passes a kernel argument `ks=cdrom:/preseed/ks.cfg` when booting.

Preseeding the Debian Installer might be the more native way to do it: https://help.ubuntu.com/11.04/installation-guide/i386/appendix-preseed.html

This thread has some other good suggestions, especially FAI: https://serverfault.com/questions/463/how-can-i-configure-unattended-installation-of-ubuntu

P.S.
There are several configuration management systems that may suit your needs if you find that configuring the machine after installation is acceptable. See especially [puppet](http://www.puppetlabs.com/), [bcfg2](http://docs.bcfg2.org/), and [chef](http://www.opscode.com/chef/).

Comment: fai: doesn't supports ext4, uses server to boot custom image

Comment: system-config-kickstart - y, doesn't do lvm/luks

Answer (score 4):

Have you tried remastersyshttp://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/backup? You have to make your system just the way you want your custom distro to be and then use remastersys to make your own Ubuntu remix disc.

Comment: remastersys doesn't supports custom rules for lvm/luks?

Answer (score 0):

I did something like this a while back with SuseStudio. That's just the name of the site, you can use any distro. Check it out. It's been a while since I've been, though.
http://susestudio.com/

### Sincerely

Andrew Hauser

Comment: this is askubuntu, i asked about ubuntu, and you're linking suse :) but thx.